# Need to iterate through firebase data

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to retrieve some data in firebase but I cannot figure out how to retrieve each expire_date value from the receipts tree

[image]

There could be 0-N quantity of "LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5I4cKN4q2" kind of receipts and N quantity of numbers inside last_receipt_info

[image]

My code since this is:

```
ref.child("recipts").once("value").then(function(questionsSnapshot) {
  return questionsSnapshot.forEach(function(questionSnapshot) {
    return console.log(questionSnapshot.val());
  });
});
```

And this actually brings me the data for all recipts but I don't know how to loop exactly the expire_date value.

I tried this lastely but did not bring data:

```
  ref.child("recipts").once("value").then(function(a) {
      a.forEach(function(a){
      a.child("latest_receipt_info").once("value").then(function(b) {
          return console.log(b.val());  //Here for every subscription I wanted to make a function
      });
    });
  });
```

Ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for ... in` loop:

```
for (var key in questionSnapshot.val()) {
    // => do what you need
}
```

I've never worked with firebase, but I think that will do what you need.

Edit:

If I'm understanding this properly, `key` in each iteration above will be something like `LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5I4cKN4q2`? If so, you can just keep nesting `for...in` loops:

```
for (var key in questionSnapshot.val()) {
    // key = LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5I4cKN4q2? something like that?

    for (var key2 in questionSnapshot.val()[key]) {
        // key2 = K_23AEu3cjcIKT1tTHf ???
        for (var item of questionSnapshot.val()[key][key2]['latest_receipt_info']) {
            console.log(item.expires_date);
        }
     }
 }
```

Edit 2:

```
for (var key in questionSnapshot.val()) {
    for (var item of questionSnapshot.val()[key]['latest_receipt_info']) {
        console.log(item.expires_date);
    }
}
```

Comment: thats good but how could be the code to print all the expires dates?

Comment: will you `console.log(key)` inside the first loop and `console.log(key2)` inside the second loop and let me know what gets printed?

Comment: return console.log(key); brings:  -K_23AEu3cjclKT1tTHf
-KYzYi3fZq3GXaOugruE  second brings nothing we're close

Comment: the best answer I've come across